# What is 'generate' in this context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What does the `generate()` method mean in the following context and how does it work? I have never seen this before. Is this a method of the `List` component, or does it belong to React.js or JSX or does it belong to Javascript or does it belong to something else? I haven't been able to locate any documentation for it.

The demo.js file [in this codesandbox contains the following](https://codesandbox.io/s/ppmxj46w8x):

https://codesandbox.io/s/ppmxj46w8x

demo.js, beginning on line 115

```
      <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
        <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
          Avatar with text
        </Typography>
        <div className={classes.demo}>
          <List dense={dense}>
            {generate(  // <-- what is this?
              <ListItem>
                <ListItemAvatar>
                  <Avatar>
                    <FolderIcon />
                  </Avatar>
                </ListItemAvatar>
                <ListItemText
                  primary="Single-line item"
                  secondary={secondary ? 'Secondary text' : null}
                />
              </ListItem>,
            )}
          </List>
        </div>
      </Grid>
```

[Here are the docs the code sandbox comes from.](https://material-ui.com/demos/lists/#interactive)

Could someone please explain and point me to some documentation for this `generate()` method.

Comment: If I understood correct, it has no direct relation to React. It's just a custom defined somewhere function, expecting React element as argument.

Comment: Look at the top of the `demo.js` file (Line 33). It is defined there. It is just a small helper method to generate multiple elements for this specific example. Not part of `react` or `material-ui` in any form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's creating key value pairs for the passed in element:

```
function generate(element) {
  return [0, 1, 2].map(value =>
    React.cloneElement(element, {
      key: value, // value = 0, 1, 2
    }),
  );
}
```

For example, line on 82 (it would just be appending a key):

```
<ListItem key={value}>
  <ListItemText
    primary="Single-line item"
    secondary={secondary ? 'Secondary text' : null}
  />
</ListItem>
```

Which translates to:

```
<ListItem key={0}>
  <ListItemText
    primary="Single-line item"
    secondary={secondary ? 'Secondary text' : null}
  />
</ListItem>
<ListItem key={1}>
  <ListItemText
    primary="Single-line item"
    secondary={secondary ? 'Secondary text' : null}
  />
</ListItem>
<ListItem key={2}>
  <ListItemText
    primary="Single-line item"
    secondary={secondary ? 'Secondary text' : null}
  />
</ListItem>
```